# package org.apache.http.client does not exist

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio

I am trying to check log in credentials , But I am getting these errors again and again , I have tried everything. I am new to android 
Any kind of help will be appreciated. If there is other good way to implement same , want to know how to imply

Error

```
Error:(19, 30) error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
Error:(15, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(16, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(17, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(18, 30) error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
Error:(20, 37) error: package org.apache.http.client.entity does not exist
Error:(21, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(22, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
Error:(23, 31) error: package org.apache.http.message does not exist
Error:(79, 22) error: cannot find symbol class NameValuePair
Error:(85, 49) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(86, 21) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(86, 45) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(88, 44) error: cannot find symbol class UrlEncodedFormEntity
Error:(90, 21) error: cannot find symbol class HttpResponse
Error:(92, 21) error: cannot find symbol class HttpEntity
Error:(105, 26) error: cannot find symbol class ClientProtocolException
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(85, 21) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient
Error:(81, 40) error: cannot find symbol class BasicNameValuePair
Error:(80, 40) error: cannot find symbol class BasicNameValuePair
Error:(79, 68) error: cannot find symbol class NameValuePair
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.tarun.proxy_maar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view){
        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        login(username,password);

    }

    private void login(final String username, String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uname = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];

                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://shaadi.web44.net/hello.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                    intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add that to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Or you use the `HttpURLConnection class` instead.

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: Nice, well done Patricia :)

Comment: From this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461881/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorfailed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-http-protocolve

You also need to add ' android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ' and '  <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />' to your manifest file.

Answer (score 7):

The `DefaultHttpClient` and `NameValuePair` classes were deprecated in API level 22, and removed in API level 23.

Google even took down the documentation for them.

When the documentation was still up, it recommended to switch to `HttpUrlConnection` for basic tasks such as this.

Here's a modified version of your AsyncTask that will work on API level 23:

```
  class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;
        String url = "http://shaadi.web44.net/hello.php";

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        DataOutputStream wr;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL urlObj;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        StringBuilder sbParams;
        String paramsString;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            sbParams = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                sbParams.append("name").append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(uname, charset));
                sbParams.append("&");
                sbParams.append("password").append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(pass, charset));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                //response from the server
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Full class code:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view){
        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        login(username,password);

    }

    private void login(final String username, String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private Dialog loadingDialog;
            String url = "http://shaadi.web44.net/hello.php";

            String charset = "UTF-8";
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            DataOutputStream wr;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            URL urlObj;
            JSONObject jObj = null;
            StringBuilder sbParams;
            String paramsString;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uname = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];

                sbParams = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    sbParams.append("name").append("=")
                            .append(URLEncoder.encode(uname, charset));
                    sbParams.append("&");
                    sbParams.append("password").append("=")
                            .append(URLEncoder.encode(pass, charset));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    urlObj = new URL(url);

                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                    conn.connect();

                    paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                    wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    //response from the server
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                conn.disconnect();

                return result.toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                    intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```