# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:failed resolution of :Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, apache-httpcomponents, android-9.0-pie

I'm encountering this error when I use Android Studio to build my app. The APK is compiled, but when I attempt to run the app on Android P emulator, it will crash and throw the following error. Please see more details in the attachments:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:failed resolution of :Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion
```

[image]

This is my build.grade file. If anybody has a suggestion on what the problem could be, I would appreciate it. Many thanks.

```
android {

     compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
     buildToolsVersion '28-rc1'
   
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    //for Lambda
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode xxxx
        versionName "Vx.x.x"

        multiDexEnabled true
     

     //other setting required
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64'
        }
```

Answer (score 900):

***Update: This is no longer a bug or a workaround, it is required if your app targets API Level 28 (Android 9.0) or above and uses the Google Maps SDK for Android 16.0.0 or below (or if your app uses the Apache HTTP Legacy library). It is now included in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library). The public issue has been [closed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779#comment11) as intended behavior.***

This is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779#comment3) on the Google Play Services side, until it's fixed, you should be able to workaround by adding this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: This is not a workaround anymore. This is the correct way now https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

Comment: @AdamK, Android 9 is API level 28. =P
(not a bug from serverside, but about P behavior change)

Comment: Anyone not using maps experiencing this as well?

Comment: Yes you may run into it as well if you use the Apache HTTP Legacy library (or one of your dependencies do).

Comment: I'm using Apache HTTP Legacy library and this just saved me. Thank you!

Comment: Does the issue with Firebase still occur? I think I got the same issue, but when using other Firebase services , such as Crashlytics

Comment: @androiddeveloper this possibly might be related to `GeoFire`.

Comment: Got the same error from using legacy Volley which was trying to access DateUtils from apache. This fix has worked.

Comment: I wasted an hour figuring this out. I even tried comparing every file with an old app (api27). Thank god I swallowed my ego and started looking here. Also big thanks to Adam and Kevin.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof, I'm using Google ads and got the exact same issue, and this fixed it.

Comment: But why this issue occurs on some devices, specifically it is causing crash on Samsung but working fine on Honor.

Answer (score 63):

This link [android-9.0-changes-28-->Apache HTTP client deprecation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p) explains reason for adding the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

> With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client.
>   Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the
>   bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.

Answer (score 37):

Do any of the following:

1- Update the **play-services-maps** library to the latest version:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0
```

2- Or include the following declaration within the `<application>` element of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Again it is a great shame for Android 9 developers and of course for Google. I hope they revise the Android 9 implementation and behavior as it has many bugs. Unfortunately, Google insists on calling these bugs, behavior changes!

Answer (score 29):

> **In your AndroidManifest.xml add this two-line.**

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

> See this below code

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 23):

If You using Android 9.0 with legacy jar than you have to use.
in your mainfest file.

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

Answer (score 20):

To run org.apache.http.legacy perfectely in Android 9.0 Pie create an xml file `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
      </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

And add 2 tags tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

> android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
>   android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest......>
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
   <activity..../> 
   ......
   ......
 <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

Also add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your app build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your application id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: This looks like something you shouldn't be doing when you intend to launch an app to the public. For development maybe it makes sense, but then it won't still work on production so there is no sense in that.

Comment: This answer should be accepted answer, I tried many ways but not worked any. Good Job @Gitesh

Answer (score 15):

It's also reported on Android bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779

Comment: And its also in documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

Answer (score 14):

If you are using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0` or below and your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above, you must include the following declaration within the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

Check this link - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

Answer (score 14):

This Might be Late Answer. but, I hope its save someone time:

If you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 or below and your app is **targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0)** or above, you must include the following declaration within the  element of **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        ...
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

       <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

</application>
```

Note: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` required for **Android 10+** to access storage R/W

Android 6.0 introduced the **useCleartextTraffic** attribute under application element in android manifest. The default value in **Android P is “false”**. Setting this to **true** indicates that the app intends to use clear network traffic.

If your app opts out of scoped storage when running on **Android 10 devices**, it's recommended that you continue to set **requestLegacyExternalStorage to true** in your app's manifest file. That way, your app can continue to behave as expected on devices that run **Android 10**

Comment: Worked for me.. well explained

Answer (score 8):

If you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 or below and your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above, you must include the following declaration within the  element of AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

This is handled for you if you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0 and is not necessary if your app is targeting a lower API level.

Answer (score 6):

In react native, I had the error not show maps and close app, run adb logcat and show error within console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:failed resolution of :Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion
```

fix it by adding within androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216533/6248208), it occurs due to an AWS SDK bug that appears to be solved [in version 2.6.30 of the SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-2630), so updating the version to a newer, can help you fixing the problem.