# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-proguard, aws-sdk-android

Similar questions have need asked already. But this one seems to be more complicated than previous ones because of changes in compatibility of Android Platforms.

Here is my error log from Pixel and Pixel2 which are signed up for Android Beta Program

```
08-16 13:20:53.146 9630-9630/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: me.project.android.dev, PID: 9630
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
        at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.<clinit>(VersionInfoUtils.java:41)
        at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.c(VersionInfoUtils.java:77)
        at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:43)
        //project specific class reference removed
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/me.project.android.dev-0SPRJnc8-4voauRU7Y20zQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/me.project.android.dev-0SPRJnc8-4voauRU7Y20zQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/me.project.android.dev-0SPRJnc8-4voauRU7Y20zQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.<clinit>(VersionInfoUtils.java:41) 
        at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.c(VersionInfoUtils.java:77) 
        at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:43) 
        //project specific class reference removed
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Same code when ran on Devices running Android 7.0 and below, it works perfectly fine.

I tried adding dependency to my project too

```
implementation "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2"
```

Adding this dependency makes the app work in Pixel and Pixel but then it crashes in all other devices with Exception saying

```
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl does not extend or implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

I tried doing all the changes in ProGuard already. Here is my proguard configuration

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-keepnames class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.* {*;}
-keepnames class org.apache.commons.logging.*
-keepclassmembers class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.* {*;}
-keepclassmembers class org.apache.commons.logging.*
-keepnames interface org.apache.commons.logging.impl.* {*;}
-keepnames interface org.apache.commons.logging.*
```

Still causing the crash.

This issue is related to Amazon AWS SDK - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/476

Is there any workaround till AWS updates their SDK to fix this issue?

Comment: whats the version for aws sdk?

Comment: @shishram cuurently i am on version 2.6.27

Comment: @MohammedAtif how you solved this issue?

Comment: @Sagar its fixed by AWS in their latest releases

Comment: @MohammedAtif I am not using `aws sdk` in project how to know where is problem

Comment: @Sagar you can trace the issue using logcat. probably one your dependencies is using these removed dependencies internally.

Comment: @Sagar try with adding this line in your menifest file.<uses-library android:name ="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required ="false"/>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is an AWS SDK bug that appears to be solved in [version 2.6.30 of the SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-2630):

> Fixed a bug where getting a logger using Apache Commons Logging would
>   crash starting Android 9.0 (Pie / API Level 28). See pull #521. Now,
>   Apache Commons Logging would be used if it's being added as a
>   dependency, otherwise android.util.Log will be used.

Answer (score 69):

Add this below line in manifest file.

```
<uses-library android:name ="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required ="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer updating the sdk itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for those like me who wonders where this <uses-library> will be used in the manifest: this will be directly under the <application tag, above <activity>.

Answer (score 17):

to fix this issue I had the dependency 
**implementation "commons-logging:commons-logging-api:1.1"**
in gradle file.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative workaround is to add the `commons-logging` library as a `.jar` file to your `libs/` folder instead of using `implementation`. Make sure that `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` is in your dependencies.

Sources of `commons-logging-1.2.jar`:

1. [Maven Repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar)
2. [Apache Commons Logging](https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/logging/binaries/commons-logging-1.2-bin.zip)

**Credit:** Dale Lim -
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/265#issuecomment-411978696

Comment: Forgot to include in question. But this approach has more conflicts than adding dependency

Answer (score 1):

```
   /*Apache Commons Logging would crash starting Android 9.0 (Pie / API Level 28).*/

   //try this 

    testImplementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'

    // in manifest  <application> s
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

     /* if this files  'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2' fails to download  then
      download this file manual  from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons- 
       logging/download_logging.cgi and paste it lib folder*/
```