# Google Maps API displaying grey screen instead of map view on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display the Google map on Android. When I load the activity i get a grey screen with the Google logo displayed in the bottom left corner. This happens using the virtual emulator and on a real device too. I have tried using a different Api key but get the same problem. I am using the Map activity provided by Android studio.

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gfs.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.LandingActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserAccountActivities.ProfileActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="redacted" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat in Error mode

```
01-02 15:06:24.913 17090-17160/E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-02 15:06:24.923 17090-17160/ E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: ***
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): ***;
```

[image]

Comment: post the logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:failed resolution of :Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461881/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorfailed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-http-protocolve)

Comment: Tried the solution from this and it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Make sure you call `onCreate()` and `onResume()` on the `MapView`.

Comment: @user10431501 add the `logcat` output. else this merely is guessing. if you have `targetSdkVersion 28` without legacy support, as the duplicate question hints for, it will certainly crash on an API 28 emulator, not an API 27 emulator.

Comment: @MartinZeitler do you want all the logcat posted?

Comment: @user10431501 think I've found the reason; updated the answer.

Comment: @MartinZeitler posted logcat in error mode, the app never crashes it just doesnt display the map. I will update my aplication to your new update on previous answer and let you know if it works.

Comment: From the logcat it looks like the problem is within my Api code?

Comment: Included screenshot of where i get the key from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com) and try to enable maps sdk for android...

Comment: I have gotten a new key three times.

Comment: the correct key is the one you get from the google console

Comment: I went to the console changed it to this key and same problem.

Comment: And it is set to enabled.

Comment: I have included screenshot.

Comment: try rebuild the app and check the logcat again

Comment: Just did this, I get the same output.

Comment: Kept on playing in the console and eventually I got a key that works.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the hardware-sensors to not required:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
    android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector"
    android:required="false"/>
```

and also this permission is not required anymore, for years:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gfs.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

and the problem actually stems from:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

which has to be moved to the very bottom of the file.

Comment: both of them are related to a different part of the project, however i did try setting them to false and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I have moved this line to the very bottom however same problem.

Comment: @user10431501 then you have to take the `logcat` output literally and a) check that indeed the correct API key is being used (also check for possible API limitations set) and also, that the Maps API had been enabled.