# DefaultHttpClient NoClassDefFoundError when switching to targetSdkVersion 28 (Android)

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

My app works perfect with

> targetSdkVersion 26

but when switching to

> targetSdkVersion 28

```
I get an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient
```

any hints , ideas ?

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your manifest file under 'application':

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Comment: I already found this before and tried, but did not work. Any other help, explanations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461881/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorfailed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-http-protocolve Can you read this answer

Comment: I forgot to clean and rebuild first, thats why it didn't work first time for me. But now its working with the above declaration. Thanks for helping.