# My android App crashes when installed in android verstion 9

Tags: android

There is no any code error in my app! It works fine in my mobile (Android verstion 8.0) BUt when i tried to install in higher verstions it crashes! The error is as follows

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
Process: com.habie.mx_video, PID: 10453
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:108)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.habie.mx_video-EWrJaUhj92vXnlwK2NRb2Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.habie.mx_video-EWrJaUhj92vXnlwK2NRb2Q==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:108) 
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96) 
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Can anyone help me what iam missing...
Thanks!!!

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p and https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Migrating-from-Apache-HTTP.

Comment: isn't this just a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461881/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorfailed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-http-protocolve)