# Class not found : com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android, http, asynchronous

I made a jar plugin for **Unity** with **Android Studio**.
My plugin use `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient`.
But the class is not found. The console of Unity shows me these errors:

```
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getParameterTypesInternal(Native Method)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:186)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1884)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source:26)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
2021/07/02 10:23:29.751 6409 6429 Error Unity Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient
```

What I can do to make the class to be found ?

Thanks for answers !

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461881/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorfailed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-http-protocolve) and [this](https://gitmemory.com/issue/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/276/508187934) could help?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidLee. I have already seen these links and the solutions don't work for me...

Comment: [This](https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http/issues/1083#issuecomment-200258055) is the most relevant source I can find.

Comment: I have already seen this solution. It doesn't explain which class must extend mine.
The used method is overrided and I have to paste it in my code without some precisions.
I'm confused.
`@override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}`

Comment: @DavidLee, I found which class to extend. It's MultiDexApplication.
Now, I added the method in my class and the lines in my gradle file.
However, The class MultiDexApplication takes the place of AsyncHttpClient : it's not found...

Comment: Have you annother idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'" between the dependencies brackets. It needs "cz.msebera.android.httpclient" to work well. Just import the class of this library you need and don't refer it in the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependencies to your gradle

```
android {        
    // ..       
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ..
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I had the dependency in my gradle file but nothing changes...
I have already looked at the link which you sent to me.
I change the minimum API level of my plugin to 23 and nothing changes too.

Comment: are you enable proguard-rules? if yes, please add this in your proguard-rules.pro: 
https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http/blob/master/library/proguard.txt

Comment: Yes, I am enable it. I added the following lines. Nothing changes...

Comment: Have you annother idea ?

Comment: try to use latest release:   implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11'

Comment: https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http

Comment: Do you think it's doesn't work because I don't use Maven ?

Comment: try to changed the dependencies to a different version (1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11), then build again until error goes away.  look at here https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http/releases

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work well with 1.4.8. Now, I have a new error when I run the project : **Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.**.
I don't have more indication.

Comment: I have modified my answer, please try with add this in your gradle: android { lintOptions { abortOnError false } }